# What is the point for using "Future" in Flutter while we do also have "asyn-await"?

Tags: flutter, async-await, future, concept

I am new to Flutter coming from a JavaScript world. In JS we also use `async-await` mechanism for asynchronous programming. But I noticed that in Dart/Flutter there is another thing named `Future` that sometimes they combine it with `async-awai` like following:

```
Future<T> function() async{ return T = await some_func();}
```

I can't distinguish between their concepts and use cases in Dart/Flutter. When should we use `Future` and when `async-await` and when we would combine both?

Comment: You can read everything in detail on https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await . It's written by dart team. Will help you to understand concept Future, Async and Await.

Comment: @RohanJariwala: Wasn't clear to me!

Comment: if you make a async method, it should be a `Future<>method`

Comment: async await is implemented underneath with Future and .then and friends.  It's important to understand how to do it with those, because occasionally, async await is too restrictive.

Comment: `await` can be used *only* on `Future`s.  There is no `async`-`await` without `Future`s.

Comment: @jamesdlin: But I think it also works when I define functions like `myFunc() async{await...}`

Comment: @best_of_man That function is still returning a `Future`.  It neglects to declare the return type, so it's treated as `dynamic`.  The thing it's `await`ing also is either a `Future` or is something with type `dynamic` that is assumed to be a `Future`.